# Querying a Key word in HIVE

Tags: jquery, hadoop, set, hive

I am trying to query a table set up in Hadoop with HIVE and one particular SELECT query I run error's with "FAILE TO RECOGNIZE INPUT NEAR 'SET'"

I beleive the problem is beacue one of the columns I need is called 'SET' (which is a key word. )

My QueryLooks like this 
SELECT * FROM activitytable WHERE set = 'vmXXXX'

What do i need to do to this query to return the information i want?
Bear in mind every other column on this table works fine

Thanks
Ighi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Hive version, try wrapping the column name set in backticks, like:

```
SELECT * FROM activitytable WHERE `set` = 'vmXXXX';
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Feel free to accept the answer if it has helped you.